# App that targets .NET 4.0 requests .NET 4.5 installation when installed with InnoSetup

Tags: .net, inno-setup

When I try to install an app that targets .NET 4.0 with InnoSetup on a Windows XP machine (our customer requires the app to work on a XP virtual machine) a message box appears that says

> To run this application, you must first install one of the following
>   versions of the .NET Framework .NETFramework,Version=4.5.1

However, if I copy the exe and all the dlls manually, the app works fine. How can I get the app working on Windows XP when installed with InnoSetup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the exe.config had the following line:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
```

Changing it to

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
```

Fixed the issue